# How to prevent Sidekiq from parallel modifications to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, multithreading, sidekiq

I have a worker that tries to find a match for a photo based on some conditions. Each photo as to have a unique match. I coded something like this:

```
class PhotoDeliveryWorker
include Sidekiq::Worker

def perform(photo_id)
  photo = Photo.find(photo_id)
  unless photo.match
    matches = Photo.where(some_condition: "some_value")
    match = matches.first

    if match
      # Do something to photo
      photo.match = match

      if photo.save
        match.some_condition = "another_value"
      else
        schedule photo_id
      end
    else
      # Couldn't find a match
      schedule photo_id
    end
  end
end
private
def schedule(photo_id)
  PhotoDeliveryWorker.perform_in 1.hours, photo_id
end
end
```

As you can see, worker gets the first model object that passes the conditions and then changes the `match` to exclude it from future workers matches list.

The issue is when several workers perform at a time, they all get the same `matches` list and as a result modify the same entity. But I need a unique match for each photo.

How can I work it around?

Additional info:

Q: Why do I use workers?

A: If I can't find a match, I need to retry later.

Q: Why do I use Sidekiq with multiple threads?

A: I need do process photos as fast as I could.

Probably I could get count of currently active workers in the beginning of each one and take nth match instead of the first. But that solution smells a bit, doesn't it?

**UPDATE:**

Additional question: Could I use something about ActiveRecord locking with this issue? I'm not very familiar with `with_lock` and all this stuff.

Comment: You could drop down to raw SQL for this: `UPDATE photos SET match_id = ? where id = ? and match_id IS NULL`. This way, only the first update will find and update record.

Comment: Assuming a simple condition, you could keep a redis list/set per condition with the Photo IDs then use `BRPOP` or `RPOP` to fetch a matching ID and ensuring this ID is never reused. 
Edit: You probably could also handle a list/set with all IDs to ensure it's not reused within redis

Answer (score 0):

a very simple solution to your problem would be to split the amount of work, so that workers don't interfere with each other.

if you have 2 workers, you could number them and do a modulo on the id `photo.id % 2`. this way you get only 0 and 1 as a result. worker with number 0 only works on his batch, worker with number 1 on the other. by increasing the modulo you can go up to whatever number of workers you want.

Comment: Actual code is much more complicated, and for each photo real set of possible matches can be different. So they are not equal, and I can't just divide this list into sections for each worker. But thank you for an interesting suggestion!

Comment: another easy solution would be to persist a worker id with the matches, so that they can be departed that way.

Comment: the usual way to do this kind of stuff would be to have a main worker that issues other workers with the matches. so you have just one worker responsible for finding matches, the rest is doing the hard stuff and get assigned just one match.